# Python loc + isin returns FutureWarning (elementwise comparison failed)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc, future-warning

```
df = df.loc[df['var'].isin(df2['this'].unique().tolist())]
```

The code above gives me a FutureWarning and I can't work out a way around it. Is this a bug or feature?

> C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\arraysetops.py:569:
> FutureWarning: elementwise comparison failed; returning scalar
> instead, but in the future will perform elementwise comparison   mask
> |= (ar1 == a)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This warning occurs when comparing "int" and "str" in your dataset. Add `.astype(str)` to your comparison dataset.
Try this

```
df = df.loc[df['var'].astype(str).isin(df2['this'].astype(str).unique().tolist())]
```